Plotting growth rate in Rayleigh-Taylor instability
I have the relation dispersion
$$\omega^{2}=\text{At}gk+\frac{k^{3}T}{\rho_{1}+\rho_{2}}$$
with $\text{At}=\frac{\rho_1-\rho_2}{\rho_1+\rho_2}$ the Atwood number and $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ the two densities. Introducing the capillary length $l_c=\sqrt{\frac{T}{g|\rho_2-\rho_1|}}$ with $T$ the surface tension and the capillary time $\tau_c=\sqrt{l_c/g}$, these can be written as
$$\tau_c \omega_\pm=\pm\sqrt{\text{At} k l_c(1+k^2l_c^2)}.$$
For long waves, i.e $k l_c <1$, the roots of the dispersion relation are purely imaginary
$$\tau_c \omega_\pm=\pm i\sqrt{(-\text{At}) k l_c(1-k^2l_c^2)}.$$
We know that the normal mode ansatz is given by
$$q=e^{-i \omega t}=e^{-i \omega_r t}e^{\omega_i t}$$
where $\omega_r$ is the real part and $\omega_i$ the imaginary part. In our case $\omega_r=0$ which means that $q=e^{\omega_i t}$. The mode corresponding to $\omega_{-}<0$ is such that $q$ decreases with time i.e its stable, the other mode $\omega_{+}$ is unstable.
I would like to plot the growth rate of the two Rayleigh-Taylor modes when the heavier fluid is on top ($\text{At}<0$), normalized to
$$\tau_{\text{ref}}=\tau_c(-\text{At})^{-1/2}$$ as a function of the normalized wave number $k l_c$ . This is my code
At = -0.1; 

lc = 1.0;  

\[Tau]ref = 1/Sqrt[-At];  

kValues = Subdivide[0, 1.5, 100];

\[Omega]plus = \[Tau]ref Sqrt[
    ComplexExpand[(-At) kValues lc (1 - kValues lc)]]; 
\[Omega]minus = -\[Omega]plus;  

\[Omega]plusIm = Im[\[Omega]plus];

\[Omega]minusIm = Im[\[Omega]minus];

plot = ListLinePlot[{Transpose[{kValues, \[Omega]plusIm}], 
    Transpose[{kValues, \[Omega]minusIm}]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick}, {Black, Dashed, Thick}}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"Unstable mode", "Stable mode"}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"k lc", "\[Omega]_i \[Tau]_ref"}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {-1, 1}}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Rayleigh-Taylor Interface Instability", 
   ImageSize -> Large];

plot

but i have

instead of

can you help me please ?

I don't know the physical meaning of these formulas, but the plot you want is obtained by just flipping the sign (-At) $\rightarrow$ (At) in the equation defining ωplus:
At = -0.1;

lc = 1.0;

\[Tau]ref = 1/Sqrt[-At];

kValues = Subdivide[0, 1.5, 100];

\[Omega]plus = \[Tau]ref Sqrt[
    ComplexExpand[(At) kValues lc (1 - kValues lc)]];
\[Omega]minus = -\[Omega]plus;

\[Omega]plusIm = Im[\[Omega]plus];

\[Omega]minusIm = Im[\[Omega]minus];

plot = ListLinePlot[{Transpose[{kValues, \[Omega]plusIm}], 
    Transpose[{kValues, \[Omega]minusIm}]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick}, {Black, Dashed, Thick}}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"Unstable mode", "Stable mode"}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"k lc", "\[Omega]_i \[Tau]_ref"}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {-1, 1}}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Rayleigh-Taylor Interface Instability", 
   ImageSize -> Large];

plot


